# How to debug / troubleshoot LSP "not in project or it is blacklisted." in lsp-mode?

Tags: lsp-mode

Recently LSP has stopped working for me.

I'm getting this message for all files in my project.

```
LSP :: example_filename.c not in project or it is blacklisted.
```

How can I investigate this, if it's blacklisted, how can I reset the blacklist?

Comment: LSP is a *protocol* so it neither works nor can stop working.  You're presumably talking about some implementation of this protocol, so please say which implementation you're using (probably `lsp-mode` or `eglot` on Emacs's side, and some LSP server on the other side but I can't begin to guess about that other side).

Comment: The question is tagged lsp-mode, but I could have included that in the title (will edit).

Comment: I had to manually add the folder to the workspace by `lsp-workspace-folders-add`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I somehow managed to blacklist my own project, removing `.lsp-session-v1` resolved the issue.

This could be located in either:

- `~/.emacs.d/.lsp-session-v1`
- `~/.config/emacs/.lsp-session-v1`

Although I might have been able to solve this using `lsp-workspace-blacklist-remove`

Comment: I don't have folder name called `~/.emacs.d/.lsp-session-*` could it be located in somewhere else?

Comment: Updated answer to show two possible locations.

Comment: I was able to find a file called `~/var/lsp/session.el` , could it be the related file?

Answer (score 5):

@capitrane comment had the answer for me: `M-x` `lsp-workspace-folders-add` from within the project, and it started to work.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19069)

Comment: There was no such answer -- it was an old comment which deserves to be an answer.

Comment: But you shouldn't just copy the comment: make it useful for naive users. E.g. I don't know much about `lsp`, so I have no idea whether what you quote is a function or a variable. I also have no idea how exactly to call the function/set the variable to add  the folder. I can guess and I know how to get around the docs to figure out how to use it, but a noob might not. So by all means, credit @capitrane, make his/her comment an answer, but don't just *copy* the comment: you spent some time to make it work for you, so explain it in enough detail to enable a naive user to use it.

Comment: Answer updated appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

`M-x lsp` works for me.  (`"Entry point for the server startup."`)